# SSL certificate for machine with Route53 DNS name, but hosted elsewhere

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, ssl-certificate

My company uses AWS for most things, and has a top level domain name registered through AWS for services hosted there. There, we have an SSL certificate for *.topleveldomain.com  However, we also have one machine that runs on Azure (they gave us some free credits...).  We gave that machine a subdomain name using Route53, pointing to the machine's public IP address.

That part works fine.

The problem that's arisen, is that we want to run on the Azure box services that require specifying SSL .key and .crt files.  So far, we've been running with a self-signed certificate, but that's causing various issues and we'd like to put a regular certificate on it.

Is there a way to do this with AWS? Certificate Manager won't let us download the .crt and .key files. We can upload the self-signed certificate, but this would not seem to cause it to be signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only types of certificates you can export from AWS ACM are ones from their [Private CA service](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/). So, in this case you'll need to obtain a proper certificate from somewhere else. You could use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to secure this server.

Comment: I'm fine with using a private one, but going through the private CA service, I need to have some other CA sign the private CA to get started.  Am I missing something, or does this still come back to using some third party?

Comment: You should be able to get and export public certificates for use with other services if you are paying for the CA service. You shouldn't need any third party, besides Amazon, to sign anything. Although I personally haven't set up a private CA on AWS. All their FAQ and Documentation would indicate you manage both private and public certificates with their ACM service after subscribing.

Answer (score 1):

Currently its not possible to use public AWS ACM certificates outside AWS.

However, there are few workarounds and approaches if it fits the nature of your application.

- Set up AWS CloudFront with ACM certificate and proxy the requests to Azure server.
- Similarly use AWS Application Load Balancer and use **target type ip** pointing to Azure server.
- If its API only load, similarly using an AWS API Gateway pointing to Azure server.
- Using [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates directly for Azure server.

Comment: This seems to have not read the question, which concerns getting .key and .crt files exported because they need to be available to an application.

Comment: You cannot export the ACM issued .key and .crt for public certificates. Can you elaborate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#services_used

> You can use `private` certificates issued with ACM Private CA with EC2 instances, containers, **and on your own servers**. (~400$/mo)
>
> At this time, `public` AWS Certificate Manager certificates can be used only with specific AWS services.